The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.[ currently i am using java 17 and vs code, flutter, `AWS amplify ]
I am developing app ,in that I am using AWs amplify for authentication. now the issue is like when I am running app from WEB the login is working fine without any compile error, but while doing from android emulator/mobile I am facing this issue.
I expecting solution for this issue

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
